# Force update for tmux status bar

Tags: tmux

I'd like to have the current time in my `tmux` status line. I got as far as:

```
$ tmux set status-right '"#22T" %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%y'
```

This does alter the time in the status line to include seconds. However, the status line is only updated if "something happens": I switch windows, switch panes, etc. How can I configure tmux to update the status-line every second, so that I can have a running clock?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could also use

```
tmux refresh-client -S
```

to manually refresh the status bar instead of relying on the refresh interval. I use it as an event driven update method, for instance when switching panes. In my .tmux.conf I changed the following:

```
bind -r k select-pane -U
bind -r j select-pane -D
bind -r l select-pane -R
bind -r h select-pane -L
```

to:

```
bind -r k select-pane -U\; refresh-client -S
bind -r j select-pane -D\; refresh-client -S
bind -r l select-pane -R\; refresh-client -S
bind -r h select-pane -L\; refresh-client -S
```

ps: In case it makes a difference, I'm using tmux 1.8 at the moment.

Answer (score 21):

Set the status inverval so that it is updated every second:

```
tmux set status-interval 1
```

Comment: But remember about CPU usage and battery life on a OSX Mavericks
http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/06/how-os-x-mavericks-works-its-power-saving-magic/